# Tabs and fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-support-library

I have created tabs in my android application by using the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. It works fine (I can swipe between tabs just as I want to), but I have a problem I can't seem to resolve.

I have a homescreen in which I add two tabs to the `ActionBar`. In the class that extends the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` I have this code:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
           return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
           return new Fragment2();

    }
    return null;
}
```

So my problem is this: In the fragments I want an activity to appear the first time that the tab is selected. Currently I have this code in the `onCreateView()` in `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`, but this happens the first time the homescreen starts, not the first time the tab is selected.

Is there any way that I can make something happen only the first time a Fragment is selected? What I want to happen the first time the tab is selected is that an Activity starts that gathers some information from the user, and this is a one-time-only event. It works, but as I have explained this page pops up when I enter the homescreen, which is not what I want.

Comment: Have a look at the docs here -- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html -- you may find a helper function that can do what you want

Comment: It sounds like you could just move the functionality from the fragments to the adapter in the main activity. The problem with doing it in the fragments is that you have no control over when they are loaded when you use a ViewPager and tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement method

> onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)

and move your code to there. For that, your activity will need to implement interface ActionBar.TabListener.

Then, you will need to keep track if this is first time tab is selected using a boolean variable.